# RegEx: How to match Prefix + Shared OR Shared + Postfix?

Tags: python, regex

Assume I want to match:

> PREFIX**something**

or:

> **something**POSTFIX

But certainly **NOT**:

> PREFIX**something**POSTFIX

Where **something** is a certain shared pattern, and PREFIX/POSTFIX are in reality also certain different patterns.

I can (or thought) solve this in Python. However this construct works for 'PREFIXabc' but does not work for 'abcPOSTFIX'. How to solve this?

```
import re 

prefix_pattern = "PREFIX" 
postfix_pattern = "POSTFIX"
shared_pattern = "[a-zA-z]*"
test_pattern ="("+prefix_pattern+shared_pattern+")|("+shared_pattern+postfix_pattern+")$"

pattern = re.compile(test_pattern)

#test = 'PREFIXabc' # Match
test = 'abcPOSTFIX' # No match

x = re.match(pattern,test)
if x:
    print(x.group())
else:
    print("Not found")
```

Comment: Then it seems it's not the real input & you don't need that `$`?

Comment: Just a note: your `$` only affects the second alternative. To make it affect both, use parentheses like `test_pattern="({0}{1}|{1}{2})$".format(prefix_pattern, shared_pattern, postfix_pattern)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that your pattern, when used with `re.match`, follows the scheme like `^(alternative1)|^(alternative2)$`. That means that the `$` end of string anchor only affects the second alternative and in case `test = 'PREFIXabc123'`, [`PREFIXabc` will get matched](https://ideone.com/ve3zZp).

There are two ways to solve it depending on your requirements.

Either you need to remove `$` and then you will also match `abcPOSTFIX` in `test = 'abcPOSTIFX123'`, or group the two alternatives:

```
test_pattern=r"(?:{0}{1}|{1}{2})$".format(prefix_pattern, shared_pattern, postfix_pattern)
```

Then, partial matches won't be found any longer.

And FYI: If the `prefix_pattern`, `shared_pattern` and `postfix_pattern` are literal strings, do not forget to use `re.escape()`.